# How to write at position in stringstream

Tags: c++

I need to write `char*` buffer to `std::stringstream` at specific position, reading through API I managed to put together following code:

```
std::stringstream ss;
char * str = "123";
ss.seekp(0);
ss.write(str, 3);
ss.seekp(1);
ss.write(str, 3);
std::cout << ss.str(); //expecting 1123
```

however does not work as expected - or more precisely does not work at all (*nothing* is ever written to the stream), the reason seem to be `.seekp()`.

---

I just managed to confirm my suspition: the `.seekp()` is to blame, after removing `ss.seekp(0)`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
char * str = "123";
// remove this line: ss.seekp(0);
ss.write(str, 3);
ss.seekp(1);
ss.write(str, 3);
std::cout << ss.str(); //expecting 1123
```

it prints 1123 as expected. Strangely enough, calling `ss.seekp(0)` on *empty* stream renders it unusable. Can somebody, please, explain me why is that so(a source in c++ documentation)?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am implementing RAM-disk and I decided least work would be to use `std::stringstream` as backstorage for `File` class ...so I guess I am trying *exactly* what I described. I need to store input in form of char* buffers of arbitrary size (and positions including overwriting eachother) into one data "storage" .

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/r6fbNe

Comment: That is *very* strange - have you tried compiling it with current VS version too? I have litterally ctrl+c/v the code above and it prints nothing moreover the `cout` is not to blame: `auto tmp = ss.str();` returns empty string.

Comment: @wondra From MSDN: "If the function succeeds in altering the stream position or positions, it returns the resulting stream position or one of the resulting stream positions. Otherwise, it returns an invalid stream position (-1). The default behavior is to return an invalid stream position" [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1afdz14b%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) - it is strange, but the way it is written, setting the stream to its current position (not altering) would be a valid error reason according to this text at least^^. But I agree its very strange and inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the seekp parameter:

```
ss.seekp(0)
```

tells to the stream to position at 0 relative to beginning (ie absolute) but...the stream is empty, and there's no position 0.
Change it with

```
ss.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
```

In this way it works.

Comment: You probably meant `std::ios_base::beg`, but thanks for the answer - setting direction was the key. Is there a documentation/source for finding these errors? I mean `seekp(0)` making stream unusable looks like a bug/undocumented behavior to me.